# Can't open .asp website locally in IIS (website won't connect to database)

Tags: asp.net, database, iis, web, sql-server-2012

Please Help!!!

I've been given a task from work to open an asp.net website, locally in IIS 7. I also have a database, that is created in another server. Being a total beginner in ASP.NET I have no idea what I'm actually doing, but fortunately I've successfully attached the database to my own SQL Server. After i added the website in IIS Manager, it gives me the following error:

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

/mk/_settings.asp, line 16

I've tried changing some things in the line 16 (which is the connection string) but I still get different '80004005' errors. I've been told by a coworker (who won't help me with the website) that I should change settings in the SQL Server Management Studio. I'm not sure what to do!

I'd also like to add that I'm using Windows 7, IIS 7 and SQL Server Express 2012. The connection string of the website is:

konStr.Connectionstring = "driver={SQL Server};server=DNS1-1\SQLEXPRESS;uid=presss;pwd=51Net78A;database=Netpress"

Can you please help me and tell me if I should change some settings in the IIS Manager or the SQL Server Management?

If you need any more information, let me know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are connecting directly to a SQL Server database, then you won't need a ODBC provider for this.
Change the connection string to:

```
konStr.Connectionstring = "server=DNS1-1\SQLEXPRESS;uid=presss;pwd=51Net78A;database=Netpress"
```

Now, make sure the server (DNS1-1\SQLEXPRESS) it's the correct name of your SQL Server Express instance

Comment: Thank you very much, I finally did it! Only thing I changed was the server (DNS1-1 is not mine, so i placed my server there and the website opened). Now, the only problem is that when i write the website's host name as an url, it opens the dir of the website's folder. If I disable Directory Browsing in IIS Manager it gives me error:      

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Is there anything i can do to open the website directly?

Comment: You have to set your default document in IIS which a web page (usually your home page) that will be used by IIS to "redirect" requests when only the domain name is specified in the url. For example, if your home page is called "Index.html" you can set that as your default document, so when you browse to http://www.yoursite.com IIS will serve your default document

Answer (score 0):

Open SS Managemet Studio, and try to open a new connection to DNS1-1\SQLEXPRESS, using the user and password in the connection string.

Probably, you won't be able to conect to the DB. If so, what you need to do is to create a new login in the SQL Server Management Studio (presss), set its password to '51Net78A' and give it permissions on the database that you attached (NetPress).

Make sure that you type the same password and username in the connection string and the login definition in the Management Studio. (Is presss, with triple s misstyped?)

Of course, you must also make sure that your machine name is DNS1-1, and that the database instance that you installed is SQLEXPRESS.

Don't blame ASP or IIS until you're able to log with the given user and password, and make a select in the database in SS Management Studio.

Comment: I have created a login with permissions and everything and I managed to log with the user only on one PC (and I've tried on two), and luckily the website opened.But, now as I've said in the previous comment when i write the host name in url first thing I get is the website's dir, and after i press the specific folder, then the website opens.

Comment: Add a new question, so that it can be answered